# Count specific data from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to count the number of entries based on the color inputted by user , like if user input red , the program should return 11. This is what I tried. The variable cnt is not defined after the loop.

```js
let description=[
                {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
                {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
                {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
                {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
                ];
{description.map((t,index) =>{
         let cnt=0;
         if(t.color=='red'){
            cnt=cnt+parseInt(t.qty);    
         }
         console.log(cnt);
      }   
      )}
 console.log(cnt);
```

Comment: `let` is scope specific. It's going to be re-created on each iteration and won't be defined once you leave it. Instead move it outside of your function and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem on your code is you initialise `let cnt=0;` inside the function and  on every reiteration, which means you are not actually adding the values since you are resetting the `cnt` to 0 on every loop.

You can use `reduce` and test if color is `colorToSearch`, if the same add the accumulator and current qty value.

```js
let description=[
     {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
     {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
     {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
     {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
     {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
     {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
];

let colorToSearch = 'red';

let totalQty = description.reduce((c, v) => v.color === colorToSearch ? c + v.qty : c, 0)

console.log(totalQty);
```

Comment: ah you beat me by few seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array first and apply reduce like below

```js
let description=[
                {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
                {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
                {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
                {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
                ];
                
 let s=description.filter(description => description.color === 'red').reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {
                 return sum + (parseInt(currentValue.qty) || 0);},0)
 console.log(s);
```

Comment: hmm . I saw parse int on OP's post and its easy to check falsey value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const description=[
  {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
  {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
  {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
  {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
  {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
  {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
];
const color = 'red';
const qty = description.reduce((a, v) => a + (v.color == color ? v.qty : 0), 0);

console.log(qty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either array filter or array reduce method. Below is an example with array reduce.

In you program `let cnt=0;` is inside the `map` function. So the value of `cnt` will not be available in the second `console.log` statement

```js
let description = [{
    color: 'red',
    qty: 6,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    qty: 5,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    qty: 5,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    qty: 5,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    qty: 5,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  },
  {
    color: 'white',
    qty: 5,
    remarks: 'asdf'
  }
];



function getCount(matchedColor) {
  return description.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    //Now checking if the color is matching with supplied paramenter
    if (curr.color === matchedColor) {
      acc += curr.qty // add with previous value
    };
    return acc
  }, 0) // zero is initial value, that is initially the sum is zero
}
console.log(getCount('red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ctn` is re-defined on each iteration and only exist within your `.map` function. That's why you get an error *"The variable cnt is not defined"* after the loop finishes.

All you need to do is move `ctn` outside of your `.map` and it will work:

```js
let description=[
                {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
                {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
                {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
                {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
                {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
                ];
                
let cnt=0;    

description.map((t,index) => {
         if(t.color=='red'){
            cnt=cnt+parseInt(t.qty); //Note: parseInt() isn't needed if qty is always a number
         }
      });
      
 console.log(cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think using `filter` then `reduce` to get the sum is a more readable solution.

```js
let description = [
  {color:'red',qty:6,remarks:'asdf'},
  {color:'green',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},
  {color:'red',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                             
  {color:'yellow',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                         
  {color:'blue',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'},                           
  {color:'white',qty:5,remarks:'asdf'}
];
let result = description.filter(item => item.color === 'red').reduce((prev, {qty}) => prev + qty, 0);
console.log(result);
```